# DisplayRequest is not working on windows universal app

Tags: win-universal-app

I'm creating a windows 10 universal app, that uses a mediaPlayerElement for playing a mp4 file hosted on an internet server.

The video plays well but when the screen locks the app is paused. I have found that I should use DisplayRequest to keep the screen off. I have include the code referenced on  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaPlayerElement.aspx
but still doesn't work and when I debug the Application on the computer, the App crashes after invoking DisplayRequest, the exception is:

Activating a single-threaded class from MTA is not supported

I have copied and pasted the example as it is, targeting anniversary update on both x64 and ARM.

Any help will be greatly appreciate it

Cheers,
H

Code below:

```
//Video url is on the button tag, I have commented out the code as it doesn't work
private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = sender;
        if (source.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            var button = source as Button;

            Player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(button.Tag.ToString()));
            //if ((Player.MediaPlayer != null) && (!isPlayerSet))
            //{
            //    Player.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackStateChanged += MediaPlayerElement_CurrentStateChanged;
            //    isPlayerSet = true;
            //}

        }
    }

//I have copied the below from the referenced url
 private void MediaPlayerElement_CurrentStateChanged(MediaPlaybackSession sender, object args)
    {
        MediaPlaybackSession playbackSession = sender as MediaPlaybackSession;
        if (playbackSession != null && playbackSession.NaturalVideoHeight != 0)
        {
            if (playbackSession.PlaybackState == MediaPlaybackState.Playing)
            {
                if (appDisplayRequest == null)
                {
                    // This call creates an instance of the DisplayRequest object
//This line throws the exception when debugging                    
appDisplayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
                    appDisplayRequest.RequestActive();
                }
            }
            else // PlaybackState is Buffering, None, Opening, or Paused.
            {
                if (appDisplayRequest != null)
                {
                    // Deactivate the display request and set the var to null.
                    appDisplayRequest.RequestRelease();
                    appDisplayRequest = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you invoke DisplayRequest in UI thread not a thread pool thread.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the response, can you please explain what do You mean? I'm calling it on the code behind of the view that contains the mediaplayerelement, I'll say that is UI. Cheers

Comment: In what event handler you call the method? Please include the calling code that throws exception in the question.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz I have added the code, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the [RequestActivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.requestactive) method on UI Thread. Calling the method on a non-UI thread results an exception:

> Activating a single-threaded class from MTA is not supported.

You have attached the `MediaPlayerElement_CurrentStateChanged` method to the [MediaPlayer.CurrentStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.currentstatechanged) event which is fired a non-UI thread, it leads to calling `RequestActivate` in a non-UI thread that ends up with an exception.

To solve the issue, add a different method for handling the event, and use the dispatcher to execute the code in UI thread:

```
private CoreDispatcher dispatcher;
public MainPage() {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
}
private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    ..
    ..
    Player.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackStateChanged += PlaybackSession_PlaybackStateChanged;
    ..
} 
private PlaybackSession_PlaybackStateChanged(object sender, MediaPlaybackSession sender, object args) {
    dispatcher.RunAsync(DispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
        //
        // Code to keep display on
        //
    });
}
```